# Suggest some freeware GUI Automation Testing tools for Windows Desktop Applications

Tags: automated-testing, test-automation-framework, coded-ui-tests, uiautomation, desktop-application

Please suggest some tools for automated GUI Testing of Windows Desktop Application. Freeware tools which can compete with Coded UI test projects.

Comment: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/7904/8992

Comment: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/8802/what-are-some-good-open-source-ui-testing-tools-for-testing-windows-gui?rq=1

Comment: This question is a duplicate of 8802

Answer (score 0):

@Michael Durrant has pointed out a lot of the essentials in his comments already. From personal experience:

I'd recommend [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org), which is strong visually but somewhat buggy overall.

Also [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/) is nice for standard Windows components, if rather limited otherwise.

References:
[What are some good open source UI Testing tools for testing Windows GUI?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/8802/what-are-some-good-open-source-ui-testing-tools-for-testing-windows-gui?rq=1)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_GUI_testing_tools
http://www.sikuli.org
https://www.autoitscript.com/site/